# How to make multiple views in android to move..?

Tags: android

I have two image views when i have implemented the on touch only one view was able to move whole the layout but other image view was at the kept at the fixed position how can we make other image view to move from one place to other If it doesn't place code for movement of multiple view Help out plz.. friends

Comment: i dont have the code which is working perfect can i have any example code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have written this code long time ago, see if it works for you

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.DisplayMetrics;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnTouchListener;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;
import android.widget.FrameLayout.LayoutParams;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class DragAndDropActivity extends Activity {
    public FrameLayout board;

    int dropZone1_X, dropZone2_X, dropZone3_X, dropZone1_Y, dropZone2_Y,
            dropZone3_Y, movingCoordinateLeft = 0, movingCoordinateTop = 0;

    int windowHeight, windowWidth, defaultMargin = 150;
    ImageView answerOption1, answerOption2, answerOption3, dropZone1,
            dropZone2, dropZone3;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        board = new FrameLayout(this);
        setContentView(R.layout.layout);

        /*
         * set id's of view objects
         */
        setIds();

        /*
         * set on touch listener
         */
        setOnTouchListener();
        /*
         * get window dimensions
         */
        getWindowDimensions();

    }

    private void setOnTouchListener() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        answerOption1.setOnTouchListener(dragt);
        answerOption2.setOnTouchListener(dragt);
        answerOption3.setOnTouchListener(dragt);

    }

    private void setIds() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        board = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.Board);
        // ids for answer options
        answerOption1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.answer_option_1);
        answerOption2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.answer_option_2);
        answerOption3 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.answer_option_3);

        // ids for drop zones
        dropZone1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.frame1);
        dropZone2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.frame2);
        dropZone3 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.frame3);

    }

    /*
     * 
     * Get default view dimensions at run time
     */

    @Override
    public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
        super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
        if (hasFocus) {

            System.out.println("Method--onWindowFocusChanged");

            System.out.println("\n\nFirst drop zone dimensions");
            System.out.println("left margin-->" + dropZone1.getLeft());
            System.out.println("top margin-->" + dropZone1.getTop());

            System.out.println("\n\nSecond drop zone dimensions");
            System.out.println("left margin-->" + dropZone2.getLeft());
            System.out.println("top margin-->" + dropZone2.getTop());

            System.out.println("\n\nThird drop zone dimensions");
            System.out.println("left margin-->" + dropZone3.getLeft());
            System.out.println("top margin-->" + dropZone3.getTop());

        }
    }

    private void getWindowDimensions() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
        getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
        windowHeight = metrics.heightPixels;
        System.out.println("window height" + windowHeight);
        windowWidth = metrics.widthPixels;
        System.out.println("window width" + windowWidth);

    }

    // onCreate
    OnTouchListener dragt = new OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            FrameLayout.LayoutParams par = (LayoutParams) v.getLayoutParams();
            switch (v.getId()) {// What is being touched
            /***
             * 
             * Answer option 1
             * 
             * ***/
            case R.id.answer_option_1: {
                // Which action is being taken
                switch (event.getAction()) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE: {
                    par.topMargin = (int) event.getRawY()
                            - (v.getHeight() + 22);
                    par.leftMargin = (int) event.getRawX()
                            - (v.getWidth() / 2 + 150);

                    movingCoordinateLeft = (int) event.getRawX()
                            - (v.getWidth() / 2 + 0);
                    movingCoordinateTop = par.topMargin;

                    System.out.println("Answer 1 --- left"
                            + movingCoordinateLeft + "---top"
                            + movingCoordinateTop);

                    v.setLayoutParams(par);

                    break;
                }// inner case MOVE
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP: {
                    par.height = 40;
                    par.width = 40;
                    /*
                     * par.topMargin = (int) event.getRawY() - (v.getHeight() +
                     * 15); par.leftMargin = (int) event.getRawX() -
                     * (v.getWidth() / 2 + 90);
                     */

                    if (windowHeight < 460) {
                        par.topMargin = 109;
                        par.leftMargin = 0;
                        par.height = 22;
                        par.width = 105;

                    } else {
                        par.topMargin = defaultMargin;
                        par.leftMargin = 0;
                    }

                    // check if co-ordinates matched and drop answer in drop
                    // zone
                    if ((movingCoordinateLeft > 10 && movingCoordinateLeft < 80)
                            && (movingCoordinateTop > 10 && movingCoordinateTop < 100)) {

                        System.out.println("left " + movingCoordinateLeft
                                + "top  " + movingCoordinateTop);

                        dropZone1.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(
                                R.drawable.duck));
                        answerOption1.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

                    }

                    v.setLayoutParams(par);
                    break;
                }// inner case UP
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: {

                    System.out.println("left" + event.getRawX());
                    System.out.println("top" + event.getRawY());

                    if (windowHeight < 460) {

                        par.height = 40;
                        par.width = 40;

                    } else {
                        par.height = 40;
                        par.width = 40;
                    }

                    v.setLayoutParams(par);
                    break;
                }// inner case UP
                }// inner switch
                break;
            }// case pawn

            /***
             * 
             * Answer option 2
             * 
             * ***/

            case R.id.answer_option_2: {// Which action is being taken
                switch (event.getAction()) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE: {

                    par.topMargin = (int) event.getRawY()
                            - (v.getHeight() + 22);
                    par.leftMargin = (int) event.getRawX()
                            - (v.getWidth() / 2 + 150);

                    movingCoordinateLeft = (int) event.getRawX()
                            - (v.getWidth() / 2 + 0);
                    movingCoordinateTop = par.topMargin;

                    v.setLayoutParams(par);

                    break;
                }// inner case MOVE
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP: {
                    par.height = 40;
                    par.width = 40;
                    /*
                     * par.topMargin = (int) event.getRawY() - (v.getHeight() +
                     * 15); par.leftMargin = (int) event.getRawX() -
                     * (v.getWidth() / 2 + 90);
                     */

                    if (windowHeight < 460) {
                        par.topMargin = 150;
                        par.leftMargin = 0;
                        par.height = 40;
                        par.width = 40;

                    } else {
                        par.topMargin = 200;
                        par.leftMargin = 0;
                    }

                    // check if co-ordinates matched and drop answer in drop
                    // zone
                    if ((movingCoordinateLeft > 120 && movingCoordinateLeft < 200)
                            && (movingCoordinateTop > 10 && movingCoordinateTop < 100)) {

                        System.out.println("left " + movingCoordinateLeft
                                + "top  " + movingCoordinateTop);

                        dropZone2.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(
                                R.drawable.hen));
                        answerOption2.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    }

                    v.setLayoutParams(par);

                    break;
                }// inner case UP
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: {

                    if (windowHeight < 460) {

                        par.height = 40;
                        par.width = 40;

                    } else {
                        par.height = 40;
                        par.width = 40;
                    }

                    v.setLayoutParams(par);
                    break;
                }// inner case UP
                }// inner switch
                break;
            }// case pawn2

            /***
             * 
             * Answer option 3
             * 
             * ***/

            case R.id.answer_option_3: {// Which action is being taken
                switch (event.getAction()) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE: {

                    par.topMargin = (int) event.getRawY()
                            - (v.getHeight() + 22);
                    par.leftMargin = (int) event.getRawX()
                            - (v.getWidth() / 2 + 150);

                    movingCoordinateLeft = (int) event.getRawX()
                            - (v.getWidth() / 2 + 0);
                    movingCoordinateTop = par.topMargin;

                    v.setLayoutParams(par);

                    break;
                }// inner case MOVE
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP: {
                    par.height = 40;
                    par.width = 40;
                    /*
                     * par.topMargin = (int) event.getRawY() - (v.getHeight() +
                     * 15); par.leftMargin = (int) event.getRawX() -
                     * (v.getWidth() / 2 + 90);
                     */

                    if (windowHeight < 460) {
                        par.topMargin = 191;
                        par.leftMargin = 0;
                        par.height = 40;
                        par.width = 40;

                    } else {
                        par.topMargin = 250;
                        par.leftMargin = 0;
                    }

                    // check if co-ordinates matched and drop answer in drop
                    // zone
                    if ((movingCoordinateLeft > 220 && movingCoordinateLeft < 310)
                            && (movingCoordinateTop > 10 && movingCoordinateTop < 100)) {

                        System.out.println("left " + movingCoordinateLeft
                                + "top  " + movingCoordinateTop);

                        dropZone3.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(
                                R.drawable.queen));
                        answerOption3.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    }
                    v.setLayoutParams(par);

                    break;
                }// inner case UP
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: {
                    System.out.println("down");
                    if (windowHeight < 460) {

                        par.height = 40;
                        par.width = 40;

                    } else {
                        par.height = 40;
                        par.width = 40;
                    }
                    v.setLayoutParams(par);
                    break;
                }// inner case UP
                }// inner switch
                break;
            }// case pawn2

            }// switch
            return true;
        }// onTouch

    };// dragt

}
```

and layout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/rl"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/frame3"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:src="@drawable/drag_drop_button" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/frame2"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/frame3"
            android:src="@drawable/drag_drop_button" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/frame1"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/frame2"
            android:src="@drawable/drag_drop_button" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/Board"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/answer_option_1"
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginTop="150dp"
            android:background="@drawable/duck" >
        </ImageView>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/answer_option_2"
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/answer_option_1"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginTop="200dp"
            android:background="@drawable/hen" >
        </ImageView>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/answer_option_3"
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginTop="250dp"
            android:background="@drawable/queen" >
        </ImageView>
    </FrameLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: it view is returned back to the original position how can the view can be placed the position where we are dragged and placed it

Comment: thanks for the code i want the zoom option for the image view

Comment: how can we save state or position of imageview