# Update the position of textview/imageview at relative layout after moving it by touch

Tags: android, layout, touch, motion

I want to have possibility to change position of items(textviews/imageview) on the screen by using touch. So I made OnTouchListener which looks like this:

```
float x = 0,y = 0 ;
private void clickOnObjectTaker() {

    cream.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener(){

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            boolean touched= false;

            if(event.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
            {
              messageMaker("touched");
              x= event.getX();
              y= event.getY();
            }

            if(event.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE )
            {
                Animation anim = 
                new TranslateAnimation(x, event.getX(), y, event.getY());
                anim.setFillAfter(true);
                anim.setFillEnabled(true);
                cream.startAnimation(anim);
                x= event.getX();
                y= event.getY();
            }
            if(event.getAction()== MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL)
            {
                cream.setX(x);
                cream.setY(y);
            }               
            return true;
        }});    
}
```

My problem is that when i change the position of object, the listener don't get new position, so I see the object in different place on the screen, but when I want to move it I must click on old position. I thought i solve it by adding this lines:

```
if(event.getAction()== MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL)
            {
                cream.setX(x);
                cream.setY(y);
            }
```

but nothing changed.

UPDATE: I tried with this code. There |I haven't any problems with updating position element of layout, everything works properly except the process of moving object by touch.
What I don't like it in this method:

- touched object vibrate when I move it (it doesn't look nice),
- object doesn't follow perfectly my finger, like somewhere I should scale the coordinates  ( for example I moved object from right to left side of screen, when my finger stops at the brink of screen, the object is lag behind of it.)

this two things makes this method useless for me.

```
@Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

        if(event.getAction()== MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
                    dx = event.getX()-v.getX();
                    dy = event.getY()-v.getY();
                }
       if(event.getAction()== MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE)
                {
                    v.setX(event.getX()-dx);
                    v.setY(event.getY()-dy);
                }



          return true;
    }

}
```

The moving of oobject in method with animation looks great for me, everything works fluently. Only problem is connected with update layout, when I add code like this

```
if(event.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_UP )
   {
     v.setX(event.getX());
     v.setY(event.getY());
   }
```

It put object at random position (I can't figure out, from what place he take this position), If somebody can give me any advice I would be grateful

EDITED

This code almost perfectly I could make repeatedly moves on view. It have two flaws:

- small reallocation after Move gesture ends
- During moving the view if I stop the finger on the screen, I can see the flashes of view at old position.

the code

```
OnTouchListener dealingwithproblems = new OnTouchListener()
    {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch( View v, MotionEvent event) {


            if(event.getActionMasked()== MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
                        //values for 
                        dx = event.getX()-v.getX();
                        dy = event.getY()-v.getY();
                        x= event.getX();
                        y= event.getY();
                    }
           if(event.getActionMasked()== MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE)
                    {
               Animation anim = 
                        new TranslateAnimation(x, event.getX() , y, event.getY());

                      //anim.setFillAfter(true);
                        anim.setFillEnabled(true);
                        v.startAnimation(anim);
                        x= event.getX();
                        y= event.getY();                           
                    }   

           if(event.getActionMasked() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP)
           {
                        v.setX(event.getX()-dx);
                        v.setY(event.getY()-dy);
           }
            return true;
               }        
    };
```

If somebody knew how to improve it, leave the answer pliz

Comment: Refer to this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19515313/how-to-make-multiple-views-in-android-to-move/19516275#19516275

Comment: It's not works perfectly for me, coause in relative layout pos of view is connected with each other so when I move one the others change position too. I tried a lot with animations and different get position methods, but I have problem with scales, every of them shows the value in misc unit.

Answer (score 0):

it maybe animation problem, you are using ViewAnimation try to use change that in Object animator. it supports form API 11.

ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(view,"Translate",x,y,toX,toY);

Comment: thx, for answer I'm going to try it in next week because I have to much work now.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem (touched object vibrates on move) and resolved it by using `getRawX()` and `getRawY()` instead of `getX()` and `getY()`